# How can I use a Rock Candy Xbox 360 controller on 64-bit Windows 10?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, windows-10

[Existing instructions](https://steamcommunity.com/app/219150/discussions/0/846944689676911746/) for using a Rock Candy Xbox 360 wired controller on Windows seem to refer only to Windows 7/8. Specifically, they suggest downloading and installing [Xbox 360 Accessories Software](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-au/d/xbox-360-controller-for-windows), which is only available for 32-bit Windows 7, before modifying an `.inf` file.

Do I follow the same instructions on Windows 10, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [the manufacturer does not officially support Windows PC](https://support.pdp.com/hc/en-us/articles/205270297-Why-doesn-t-my-controller-work-on-a-PC-), you do not need to follow any special instructions on Windows 10.

Simply plug the Rock Candy controller into your USB port. The first time you do this, Windows 10 will detect and configure it automatically. Every time thereafter, it will simply be detected and ready to use.

(Tested December 2017 with an up-to-date Windows 10 installation. These instructions should continue to work without issue.)

Comment: This does not work. Nothing happens when you plug in the rock candy xbox 360 controller. it's listed as an unknown device under device manager, and I can not locate drivers.